Customize print action to use a template
I have to create 2 PDF file from contribution line items. These reports are called "Libro Soci" (book of members) and they must have precise formatting as these:

The second report starts from Memberships and displays a summary of all shares and paid-up capital.

I could start from Line Item Report extension, but I don't know if it is possible to customize "print" action to use a specific template.
Alternatively, I was thinking to make an extension that adds a 'Print from template' action that creates a PDF from the search results and asks you for the template to use.
Can you give me some suggestions? Maybe there is something ready-made.
Thanks.
PS: I think I cannot use "Thank-You Letters for Contributions" because it prints a page for every contribution o contract group of contributions. My requirement is to have a single tabular pdf, like an Excel, but customised.

If you make a civireport then you can have the tpl use any layout you like. You could have it extend the lineitem report and then only update the tpl.
